# Are movie and TV show recommendations on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

In my opinion, movie and TV show recommendations should be **off-topic** on our site. The following is an example for that, and I voted to close.

[Some TV Shows like “The Big Bang Theory”](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/1773/56)

If mods agree with me, I suggest we add this to [faq](https://movies.stackexchange.com/faq) page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Opinions about a Movie / TV show" is already in the FAQ, and this is meant to mean recommendations too. I will update the FAQ to make it more explicit.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes _opinions_ and _recommendations_ may not mean the same. The word "recommendations" should be included for the sake of clearness.

Comment: @MehperC.Palavuzlar: Recommendation questions have always been flagged and closed in the past - we've just not made the FAQ explicit enough.  Done now - Thanks.